# How to change graph layout engine used in pydot?

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot

I'm currently using pydot to generate some graphs for a school project, and I want to experiment with using different graph layout engines to generate the graphs. At the moment, all my graphs are created using the Dot layout engine, but I'd like to be able to change this to Neato/ other layout engines. Is this possible in pydot, or is there a different Graphviz interface I can use that has this functionality?

Answer (score -1):

You can output a text file that can then be read by the various Graphviz engines.  From the pydot documentation:

```
# As a string:
output_raw_dot = graph.to_string()
# Or, save it as a DOT-file:
graph.write_raw("output_raw.dot")
```